# how to import modules that require arguments

Tags: node.js, express, module, sequelize.js

this is my files sturcture:

```
-models
    -user.js
    -room.js
    -database.js
-controllers
    -createRoom.js
    -routes.js
    ..
```

user.js and room.js are modules i want to import in database.js. right now im doing like this:

in database.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = new Sequelize('test', 'root', 'root', {
dialect: "mysql", 
port: 3306

})
var User = require('./user.js')(Sequelize, db);
var Room = require('./room.js')(Sequelize, db);


module.exports = function(){

    //code...   

};
```

in user.js/room.js

```
module.exports = function (Sequelize, db) { 

var Room = db.define('Room', {
    room_id : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true},
})

db
 .sync({force: true})
 .complete(function (err) {})
```

so far so good, but when i need to import user.js or room.js in other files besides database.js(eg, createRoom.js), i have trouble importing them because theres no Sequelize and db defined like in the database.js. does it mean i have to connect to the database and require Sequelize again whenever i need to use user.js and room.js module in other files? is there a better way to work around this?? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have different possibilities here

1. re-export models:

   in your database.js

   ```
   //init code as seen
   module.exports.Room = Room
   ```

   importing somewhere else

   ```
   require('../models/database').Room
   ```
2. make your database.js dependency

   in database.js

   ```
    module.export = { Sequelize: Sequelize, db : db}
   ```

   in room.js

   ```
    var dbModule = require('./database')
    module.exports = dbModule.Sequelize.define('Room', /*....*/)
   ```
3. Attach the model to the init function

   in room.js

   ```
   module.exports = roomInit

   function roomInit(Sequelize, db) { 

     roomInit.Room = db.define('Room', {
       room_id : {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true}
   })

    db
      .sync({force: true})
      .complete(function (err) {})
    }
   ```

   usage

   ```
    require('./room').Room
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. the #2 looks like a good approach to me but Sequelize and db dont seem to be exported. it said dbModule.Sequelize was undefined.

Comment: if your database.js looks exactly like in your example then just attach new properties after the main export. in your example there is a module.exports= function already, so you have to attach additional exports to it

Comment: what do you mean by attaching?

Comment: module.exports = function(){};
module.exports.Sequelize = Sequelize;
module.exports.db = db;